# Attempting to understand a theorem regarding subsequences and convergence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am attempting to understand the following theorem.

**Theorem**: Let ($s_n$) be a sequence. If $t$ is in $\mathbb{R}$ then there is a subsequence of ($s_n$) converging to $t$ if and only if the set {$n\in\mathbb{N} : |s_n - t| < \varepsilon$} is infinite for all $\varepsilon > 0$.

It seems to me that this is saying that a subsequence converges to a real number $t$ if and only if there exist an infinite number of $\varepsilon$'s and corresponding $t$'s such that $|s_n - t| < \varepsilon$ holds.

Is my thinking correct?

Comment: No, $t$ is fixed. The condition needs to hold for **all** $\epsilon > 0$, not just infinitely many $\epsilon > 0$.

Comment: @angryavian So once you pick an $\varepsilon$ then $t$ becomes fixed as Bungo mentions? So really you're "choosing" the $n$'s?

Comment: @KingTut Sorry, my previous comment was phrased badly. You have a statement "a subsequence of $(s_n)$ converges to $t$." So this $t$ is fixed, as Bungo states. The theorem states that the above statement is equivalent to the following: "If I fix some $\epsilon>0$, then $|s_n-t|<\epsilon$ for infinitely many $n$. This works for any $\epsilon>0$."

Comment: @angryavian Oh I believe I understand now. Once you fix some $\varepsilon > 0$ there are infinitely many $n$ such that infinitely many terms of $s_n$ satisfy $|s_n - t| < \varepsilon$. Is this correct?